# Drop down in xslt

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am very new to this xslt or i am dumb  .Please help.I have a input type select(drop down) with three options- .Xml and xslt given  below .I am only getting the blank drop down.How to set the selected value into the drop down ????.Here in my case one drop down have to select "View Only" and another "Full Access".  :(

### XML

```
<PagedResult xmlns="xxxxx/Object" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RowCount>1</RowCount> 
<PageCount>1</PageCount> 
<Errors /> 
<ResultsPerPage>1</ResultsPerPage> 
<CurrentPage>1</CurrentPage> 
<Rows>
<SearchResultShare>
<ShareUserPrivilege>View Only</ShareUserPrivilege> 
</SearchResultShare>
<SearchResultShare>
<ShareUserPrivilege>Full Access</ShareUserPrivilege> 
</SearchResultShare>
</Rows>
</PagedResult>
```

### XSLT

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pg="xxxxx/Object">
                                <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
                                <xsl:decimal-format name="us" NaN="n/a"/>

                                <pg:options>
                                    <option>Select</option>
                                    <option>Full Access</option>
                                    <option>View Only</option>
                                </pg:options>
                                <xsl:variable name="options" select="document('')//pg:options/*"/>

                                <xsl:template match="/pg:PagedResult">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="pg:Errors/node()">
                                            <ul>
                                                <xsl:apply-templates select="pg:Errors"/>
                                            </ul>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="pg:RowCount = 0">
                                            <div class="tableBorderColorBGrnd tableBorderColor tableHeader">
                                                <table class="primaGridViewSmall" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr valign="bottom">

                                                        <th style="width: 3%;text-align: left;"></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <table class="primaGridViewSmall" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding: 3px;">Your search did not return any share users.</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <div class="tableBorderColorBGrnd tableBorderColor tableHeader">
                                                <table id="tblSearchResultsHeader" class="primaGridViewSmall" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr valign="bottom">
                                                   <th style="width: 3%;text-align: left;"></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="searchResultsTable" class="resultsContainer1">
                                                <table id="tblSearchResults" class="primaGridViewSmall" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">
                                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="pg:Rows"/>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:template>

                                <xsl:template match="pg:SearchResultShare">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 10%;text-align: left;">

                                            <xsl:variable name="ShareUserPrivilege" select="pg:ShareUserPrivilege"/>
                                            <select id="ShareUserPrivilege">
                                                <xsl:for-each select="$options">
                                                    <option value="{.}">
                                                        <xsl:if test=". = $ShareUserPrivilege">
                                                            <xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>
                                                        </xsl:if>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                    </option>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:template>
                            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output

```
<div xmlns:pg="xxxxx/Object" class="tableBorderColorBGrnd tableBorderColor tableHeader"><table id="tblSearchResultsHeader" class="primaGridViewSmall" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">
<tr valign="bottom"><th style="width: 3%;text-align: left;"></th></tr>
</table>
  </div><div xmlns:pg="xxxxx/Object" id="searchResultsTable" class="resultsContainer1">   
 <table id="tblSearchResults" class="primaGridViewSmall"   cellspacing="0"    cellpadding="1" border="0" width="100%">

  <tr><td style="width: 10%;text-align: left;"><select id="ShareUserPrivilege">  
 </select></td>
</tr>
  <tr><td style="width: 10%;text-align: left;"><select id="ShareUserPrivilege">
    </select></td>
</tr>
 </table></div>
```

### What i want

While page loading ,the "ShareUserPrivilege" eg: View Only, have the value user selected from the database.So on page load ,i need to set the drop down selected index to that value ,ie "Full Access" insted of "Select". Currently its not setting the selected value always come as "<--Select-->".

```
Eg:
    <--Select-->    selected index -1
    View Only       selected index 0
    Full Access     selected index 1
```

In the edit page user already selected say "full access" selected index is 1 and i have stored the selected index value 1 into the db.So now in the Listing page(or viewing page) i need to list those result .There the drop down has to set to "Full access".How?

```
output needed

   Full Access     selected index 1
   <--Select->     selected index -1
   View Only       selected index 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

```
<select name="select2" id="select2" groupID="{pg:ShareGroupID}" onchange="javascript:editedGroupPrivilegeChanges('{pg:ShareGroupID}',this);return false;">
                                                <xsl:if test="pg:ShareGroupPrivilege='View Only'">
                                                    <option value="0" selected="true">View Only</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Full Access</option>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="pg:ShareGroupPrivilege='Full Access'">
                                                    <option value="0">View Only</option>
                                                    <option value="1" selected="true">Full Access</option>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to generate `<option selected="true"/>`. In fact the HTML code `<option selected>` is an SGML shorthand for `<option selected="selected"/>`. So just change your code to generate that.

Comment: Just change `<xsl:attribute name="selected">true</xsl:attribute>` to `<xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>`

Comment: @kay:No changes :(   still the same result ;i am checking using the online tool,copy pasting the above xsl and xml and run the transformation and then press button "open result" you can see the result  in this tool http://xslttest.appspot.com/   .Can you help me out i am stuck in this

Comment: What does the HTML that you are generating look like?

Comment: @kay:While page loading ,the "ShareUserPrivilege" eg: <ShareUserPrivilege>View Only</ShareUserPrivilege>, have the value user selected from the database.So on page load ,i need to set the drop down selected index to that value ,ie "View Only" insted of "Select". Currently its not setting the selected value always come as "Select".